# All users/comments suspected as bot?

Tags: comments, users, user-registration, spam

Extremely new to WordPress and just "website making" in general here so forgive my lack of expertise - but every time I try to register an account through my site (as a test), it says "User suspected as bot" and fails. Same thing happens when trying to comment by filling in the name, email, website form; "Suspected as bot". The only way I can create an account is by making one through my administrator account, which obviously won't work for others coming to my site.

Why is it doing this and how can I stop it?

Cheers.

Comment: you probably have some security plugin that does it. disable plugins and enable them to find which one is the cause